# Rich Snippets Review Rating on Homepage

Tags: rich-snippets, homepage, website-review

I have a site which is a health service and we have independent reviews taken by a Google approved reviews website (TrustPilot).

Is it acceptable to add review Rich Snippets with our aggregate rating onto the homepage?
I haven't seen this done with any other websites but the documentation isnt very clear (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/172705?hl=en&ref_topic=1088474).

Comment: The only time I have had the review snipped show up on my sites is when we have had them on product pages.  I think turstpilot and services like theirs are more for GoogleAdwords and GoogleShopping ratings then the schema type ratings you see.   As for the schema tags, you can make up whatever you want and show a 5 star review on all of your products.   I think google has become very picky on when they show the XXXXX star ratings.   Again, they never show up for us unless if we have them for tons of products.

Answer (score 1):

No, review rich snippets should only be used in cases where "[the main topic of the page needs to be about a specific product or service.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en)" -- using them on your homepage in general wouldn't be like that.